# Task Manager and Hyper-V Logical Processor/%Total Run Time Comparison

Tags: hyper-v, performancecounter, windows-server-2019, hypervisor

On a Hyper-V host running Windows Server 2019, I observe the following picture:

The %Utilization graphs in Task Manager and the Hyper-V Logical Processor/%Total Run Time (for Total Instance) graphs in Perfmon are generally very similar, but differ by about 10%. Can you please tell me why there is such a difference? Where are these 10% hiding?

I follow the general recommendation to use Logical Processor/%Total Run Time to monitor Hyper-V performance. But I'm trying to figure out if the Task Manager really correlates with this counter.